# Unable to set up GitHub Repository

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to set up a GitHub repo for my Azure Data Factory. As you can see, I'm not having much luck. Has anyone gotten this to work?

[image]

Comment: Press F12, in the network tab, what is the response of failed api call? Or did you see any errors in console?